# How to create a thread-safe singleton in python

Tags: python, django, singleton, thread-safety

I would like to hold running threads in my Django application. Since I cannot do so in the model or in the session, I thought of holding them in a singleton. I've been checking this out for a while and haven't really found a good how-to for this.

Does anyone know how to create a thread-safe singleton in python?

EDIT:

More specifically what I wand to do is I want to implement some kind of "anytime algorithm", i.e. when a user presses a button, a response returned and a new computation begins (a new thread). I want this thread to run until the user presses the button again, and then my app will return the best solution it managed to find. to do that, i need to save somewhere the thread object - i thought of storing them in the session, what apparently i cannot do.

The bottom line is - i have a FAT computation i want to do on the server side, in different threads, while the user is using my site.

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure of the consequences of doing so...

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your use-case? Threads might not be the right solution.

Comment: mmm... updated my answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368302/how-to-create-a-thread-safe-singleton-in-python/6369512#6369512

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a very good reason - you should execute the long running threads in a different process altogether, and use [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) to execute them:

> Celery is an open source asynchronous
>   task queue/job queue based on
>   distributed message passing. It is
>   focused on real-time operation, but
>   supports scheduling as well.
>
> The execution units, called tasks, are
>   executed concurrently on one or more
>   worker nodes using multiprocessing,
>   Eventlet or gevent. Tasks can execute
>   asynchronously (in the background) or
>   synchronously (wait until ready).

Celery guide for djangonauts:  http://django-celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-django.html

For **singletons** and sharing data between tasks/threads, again, unless you have a good reason, you should use the **db layer** (aka, models) with some caution regarding db locks and refreshing stale data.

**Update**:  regarding your use case, define a `Computation` model, with a `status` field.  When a user starts a computation, an instance is created, and a task will start to run.  The task will monitor the `status` field (check db once in a while).  When a user clicks the button again, a view will change the status to `user requested to stop`, causing the task to terminate.

Comment: By creating a thread, aren't you extending the life of the request for as long as the computation takes? Creating threads doesn't sound good.

Answer (score 1):

If you want asynchronous code in a web application then you're taking the wrong approach. You should run background tasks with a specialist task queue like Celery: http://celeryproject.org/

The biggest problem you have is web server architecture. Unless you go against the recommended Django web server configuration and use a worker thread MPM, you will have no way to track your thread handles between requests as each request typically occupies its own process. This is how Apache normally works: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/prefork.html

EDIT:

In light of your edit I think you might learn more by creating a custom solution that does this:

- Maintains start/stop state in the database
- Create a new program that runs as a daemon
- Periodically check the start/stop state and begin or end work from here

There's no need for multithreading here unless you need to create a new process for each user. If so, things get more complicated and using Celery will make your life much easier.